# How to Enforce instantiation of immutable pojo with mandatory variables?

Tags: java, builder, pojo, lombok

### Problem Statement

I want to enforce such a situation that whenever the instance of the immutable pojo is to created all the mandatory variables must be passed in as parameters.

Let's Suppose I have Pojo like this

```
public class pojo {
    private final String str;
    private int number;
}
```

Now, As I said the pojo is immutable, I am using Lombok's Builder and Getter annotation. 
Something Like,

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class pojo {
    private final String str;
    private int number;
}
```

Now, In this pojo the variable str is mandatory, and any instance of class pojo without a valid value of str is of no requirement.

Now, Object of class Pojo can be constructed using Builder in such a way

```
pojo obj = pojo.builder().build();
```

But the field str is mandatory and the above statement will create an object with str = null and number = 0. Now i can make use of @NonNull over 
str to ensure that Object creation throws a Null pointer Exception at runtime if someone tries to build the object of pojo without specifying str.
But I want to enforce this check at compile time, Is there a way to stop object creation if str is not given as paramter?

Comment: You cannot enforce that at compile time while using a `@Builder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you write your Builder by hand. Have your `builder()` factory method return a class like `UnreadyBuilder` which doesn't have a `build()` method. Then the `setName()` setter (or whatever it's called) on `UnreadyBuilder` can return a `ReadyBuilder` object which does have a `build()` method.

That said: do you really need this to be checked at compile time? It's a lot of extra code for a pretty marginal benefit.

Comment: Well, I thought that there must exist a very elegant solution to this problem but I guess there is not. So, I believe, I should go with @NonNull.

Comment: @CroskCool Either this or drop the `@Builder` in favor of an `@AllArgsConstructor`. In case you have many fields, consider splitting the class. In case you can't, consider grouping the fields, so you can do something like `new BigPojo(new Part1(a, b, c, d), new Part2(e, f, g))`. Sadly, you have to write the constructor by hand.